# Have jest log parameters passed into a function that resulted in a test failure

Tags: jestjs

I am working on a series of jest test scripts, and to make the code a bit tighter, I am putting them in an array:

```
test('buttonPadding', function () {
  const expectedResults = [
    { iconPosition: 'center', small: true, expectedResult: undefined },
    { iconPosition: 'center', small: false, expectedResult: undefined },
    { iconPosition: 'left', small: true, expectedResult: '10px 20px 10px 20px' },
    { iconPosition: 'left', small: false, expectedResult: '17px 42px 18px 42px' },
    { iconPosition: 'right', small: true, expectedResult: '10px 20px 10px 20px' },
    { iconPosition: 'right', small: false, expectedResult: '17px 42px 18px 42px' },
  ];
  expectedResults.forEach(({ iconPosition, small, expectedResult }) => {
    expect(buttonPadding({ iconPosition, small })).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });
});
```

The downside is when an error occurs, it shows the `expect(buttonPad...` line as where the error occurred, but doesn't show what the parameters were that got passed into the tested function.

Is there something that can be passed to the `expect()` function that will allow you to output some type of log when an error occurs so I can see what made the test fail?

What I would like to know is what iconPosition and small were equal to to get the test to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can also suggest using [describe.each](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describeeachtablename-fn-timeout) or [test.each](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) like this:

```
    describe.each(
      [
        ['center', true, undefined],
        ['center', false, undefined],
        ['left', true, '10px 20px 10px 20px'],
        ['left', false, '17px 42px 18px 42px'],
        ['right', true, '10px 20px 10px 20px'],
        ['right', false, '17px 42px 18px 42px'],
      ]
      )('with params (%p, %p)', (iconPosition, small, expectedResult) => {
        it(`should return: ${expectedResult}`, () => {
          expect(buttonPadding({ iconPosition, small })).toEqual(expectedResult);
        })
      });
```

[example](https://repl.it/@StefanTeneff/buttonPadding)

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way, and one where tests are more isolated by putting the foreach outside of the `test()`

```
[
    { iconPosition: 'center', small: true, expectedResult: undefined },
    { iconPosition: 'center', small: false, expectedResult: undefined },
    { iconPosition: 'left', small: true, expectedResult: '10px 20px 10px 20px' },
    { iconPosition: 'left', small: false, expectedResult: '17px 42px 18px 42px' },
    { iconPosition: 'right', small: true, expectedResult: '10px 20px 10px 20px' },
    { iconPosition: 'right', small: false, expectedResult: '17px 42px 18px 42px' },
  ].forEach( ({iconPosition, small, expectedResult})  => {
      test(`buttonPadding with params (${iconPosition}, ${small}) => ${expectedResult}`, function () {  
            expect(buttonPadding({ iconPosition, small })).toEqual(expectedResult);
      });
  });
```

By passing the names into the test log it can show what was passed in and what the result should be when it fails.